# Copy Command's Parameters Dynamically

Tags: function, powershell, parameters

Is there a way to copy the parameters from one function, to the my current function 'dynamically'?

Ex:

```
Function CopyVerify-Item {
   DynamicParam {

     # Get all the parameters from Copy-Item

   }
   Process {

     Copy-Item $PSBoundParameters
     # Do my extra code here to verify the copy

   }
}
```

I need it to be an exact copy, with switches, mandatory, ParameterSets..

I want to use this new function, exactly like the original one, except include extra code in the function.

> ** This is a stupid/pure example of what i'm doing, but in reality, it's a lot more complex.. and don't want to have to replicate all my
>   parameters each time for each function.. and some functions are
>   created dynamically as well.. so i'm just keeping the example VERY
>   simple.

Comment: Have you considered using a ProxyCommand?   It will at least help you generate the boiler plate code you are looking to avoid having to generate.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/01/04/extending-and-or-modifing-commands-with-proxies.aspx

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK functions doesn't support inhertiance. You need to copy/paste the common parameters/code.

If you're comfortable with C# you could create cmdlets in a binary module using. Then you could use an abstract class for your common parameters. You might have to create simple override-"wrappers" for the properties to include them in ParameterSets though.

Ex.

```
public abstract class FrodeCommandBase : PSCmdlet
{
    #properties, getters setters etc.
}

public class GetFrodeCommand: FrodeCommandBase
{
}
```

You might have to create simple override-"wrappers" for the properties to include them in ParameterSets though.